# Dynamically change and restrict "AssignedTo" (People Picker Field) to select from a specific user group on Quick Edit mode?

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem, people-picker, quick-edit, gridview, sharepoint-ootb

I have a List A and List B.

List A contains the group I want to assign a task.

List B contains the person from that Group based on a lookup from List A.

However in OOTB Quick Edit Mode it shows all the users for that group.

If I can change the people picker control at the time of rendering of that view, that would be nice.

Comment: Can you elaborate more your scenario? List A contains only Group does it mean SharePoint Group?

Comment: Yes. To elaborate more, List A has the Group To which a task can be assigned. And in List B we have an AssignedTo field which is a people picker field. And in the same List we have a LookUp Field which acts as a Foreign Key to the Row it is associated with in The List A. Any Person in List B 
item must be from the group Selected in the row/item of Lookup (List).

Comment: Which version of SharePoint are you using? Are you using classic experience or modern experience?

Comment: SharePoint 2016 On-prem